# I can't seem to change a null value to a string on chart.JS

Tags: javascript, angular, null

So our framework Angular uses chartJS to generate charts. There's a problem that sometimes when the datapoint is null, the label will be blank. I can't seem to write something that replaces the null value into a string: "unknown".

```
this.responseTime = {
            ...this.responseTime,
            areaDataPoints: [...serviceDeskObject.AvarageResponsetime].sort(dataPointXComparerAsc).map(dataPoint => ({ name: getDay(dataPoint.Label, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), value: dataPoint.Y })),
          };
```

I tried `dataPoint.Label(name == null ? null : name.replace("unknown"))` but that doesn't work.